# How to distinguish rifles and shotguns in French?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

In English, there are 2 separates words for these firearms but, in French, they are both called *"fusil"*. The only distinctions I know are linked to the operating mode, which can help you guess if it's a rifle or a shotgun (*fusil à verrou* = bolt-action rifle ; *fusil à pompe* = pump-action shotgun).

However, in some cases, **you can't guess if it's a rifle or a shotgun** :

- *fusil semi-automatique*
- *fusil à levier* (often assumed to be a rifle but does not work with a Winchester 1887)
- *fusil de chasse*

From what I know, you can only guess the type of weapon based on informations given about the *"fusil"*.

Comment: I don't know a lot about firearms but I'm pretty sure you're right saying that in French we just differenciate by specifying the type of « fusil », assuming that both rifles and shotguns are members of this category.

Comment: Am I right to suppose that you are living in the United States or so? In Europe, guns are just not that much of a topic. Only a tiny group of specialists (hunters for example) would bother to differentiate various types...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "fusil de chasse" is "shotgun".

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann I'm French, I'm just interested in guns and military stuff.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi A lot of people assume it's a shotgun and call hunting rifles *carabine*, yet it's not technically valid.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain the difference in English between a rifle and a shotgun.

Comment: A rilfe is a firearm (usually long and possessing a stock) with a rifled barrel (as the name suggests), firing a single projectile and often used for medium to long range. A shotgun is a firearm with a smoothbore barrel (usually long and possessing a stock) intended for closer distance engagements. Shotgun usually fire multiple projectiles (buckshot for example), but it can fire single projectiles (slugs). They are easily distinguished by their ammunition if you have a hard time telling what is what just by looking at the gun.

Comment: Some shotguns have a rifled barrel though for increased range with slugs. That's why distinguishing them through ammo is easier.

Answer (score 7):

From their definition, the only difference between a rifle and a shotgun is that the first one has a spiraled barrel and the second a smoothbore, the two being shoulder weapons. The proper translation in French should then be:

- Rifle = carabine
- Shotgun = fusil (de chasse)

To be honest, I doubt 0.1% of the population would be able to tell the actual difference between carabine and fusil (I did not know and I will forget very soon, to be honest).

Also, in the military, shoulder weapons are usually called "fusil": fusil d'assaut (assault rifle, generic term for war guns), fusil sniper (sniper gun), fusil (semi-)automatique (semi-automatic rifle/machine gun) (1)

Fusil is usually used in informal talks as carabine is often associated with "carabine à plomb" (pellet gun) nowadays. However, it is rather common to see the word carabine in news titles like "un homme tué par une carabine" (a man killed with a rifle/shotgun), but it can be either a rifle or a shotgun.

**More on guns**

You have not asked but I will answer anyway:

- Arme à feu = firearm
- Arme de poing ("fist weapon") = handgun, i.e. firearms which are not shoulder weapons
- Chevrotine = buckshot

(1) For years, French military was equipped with semi-automatic rifles called FAMAS (Fusil d'Assaut de la Manufacture d'Armes de St-Etienne) which is being replaced with HK 416 F

Comment: Although *carabine* tends to be used for *rifle*, it is incorrect as a carabine is a particular sort of rifle. BTW, The FAMAS can fire full auto and in bursts of 3. Also, *fusil semi-automatique* can designate a semi-auto rifle or a semi-auto shotgun. A *machinegun* is *mitrailleuse*, not *fusil (semi-)automatique*

Comment: Le premier A de l'acronyme [FAMAS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAMAS) ne signifie pas _automatique_ mais _d'assaut_.

Comment: @mouviciel Oups, merci de l'avoir noté. Je l'ai corrigé dans ma réponse.

Comment: *Fusil d'assaut* is *assault rifle*, not *assault gun*. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_gun) is what an assault gun is.

Comment: Thank you @Hawker65, I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

If one takes the definition that a rifle is a gun with a rifled barrel, and a shotgun is a smoothbore barrel, then one could say

- **Fusil à canon rayé**
- **Fusil à canon lisse**

However, as you already observed, this difference is not commonly used to categorize weapons. Instead, looking at a sample of French gun retailers online, the purpose is often used (fusil de chasse, fusil d'assaut, carabine de tir longue distance, etc.), the reloading mechanism (fusil à pompe, fusil semi-automatique), or even just the ammunition stock (carabine 22 long rifle).

Comment: Yes but, usually, both *Fusil à canon rayé* and *Fusil à canon lisse* designate shotguns. *Carabine* is used more often to describe rifles (sepecially hunting rifles), even if it is incorrect